# Remove duplicate depending on Date value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to clean a database filled with duplicate values, I want to remove all duplicate with and old date. Aim:

-If Serial ID has > 1 entry, remove all but the latest date

*Asset_Table*   (Shows all duplicate Serial_ID)

```
    Serial_ID       |    ISSI     |     Date_Added
---------------------------------------------------------
 2PND00849EWS8J1    |   3766040   |  2012-07-06 08:52:23.000
 2PND00849EWS8J1    |   3778051   |  2016-09-26 09:21:57.000
```

Expected Result:

```
   Serial_ID        |    ISSI     |     Date_Added
---------------------------------------------------------
 2PND00849EWS8J1    |   3778051   |  2016-09-26 09:21:57.000
```

Comment: "I want to remove all duplicates with an old date" and "If Serial ID has > 1 entry, remove the earliest date" don't mean the same thing. I think, if the first statement is correct, the aim should be specified as "If Serial ID has > 1 entry, remove all but the latest date"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `row_number()` function to avoid duplication or delete them

```
delete d from
(
    select *,
           row_number() over(partition by Serial_ID order by Date_Added desc) rn
    from Asset_Table
) d
where d.rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
     a.Serial_ID , 
     a.ISSI ,
     Date_Added 
from Asset_table  as a 
where a.Date_Added = 
     (select max(b.Date_Added) 
      from Asset_table as b  
      where b.serial = a.serial)
```